# View file changes in git in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, repository

I can view changes made to an individual file in git (history) from the terminal.
How do I view all changes (history) to individual files in eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Egit manual](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Inspect_History):

```
right-click Team > Show in History
```

That will display the graph of commits for that file.

[image: http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/a/a8/Egit-0.11-getstarted-history2.png]

That is the equivalent of `git log`